# Allocating a path to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, memory, temporary-files

I have an image as an np array and I want to pass it to a model which just accepts the image path as the input. What is the best and most optimized way of getting a path for my image?

Writing on the disk doesn't seem reasonable for a large number of images. Is there a way to get a path on the memory?

Comment: This is very unclear. where are you getting these images? if you have their paths, why do you need their paths again?

Comment: @Nullman: The image is stored in memory as a NumPy array. There is no path, because it's a NumPy array, not a file.

Comment: I don't have the paths. I just imread some images and did some preprocessing and the images are changed, so I don't have the path for current images. I don't want to use imwrite because it's not efficient. I want to know if there is a way to get a path on RAM for example.

Comment: You may wan't to look for in-memory file systems [here](https://pypi.org/project/fs/) is an example. If you are on linux look up `tmpfs` or  just write your files to `/dev/shm` directly

Comment: Can you tell us more about the "model which just accepts the image path as the input"?  Is it an open source library, or some private code of yours?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I don't think it matters. My question is how to have a path for a NumPy array? even a temp path.

Comment: Of course it matters, it's very common in Python for functions which take a string path to also accept a file-like object or other things.

Comment: @JohnZwinck in this case it's a private code which unfortunately doesn't accept any other type.

Comment: question needs a [mre]. show that "model" that accepts only a file path.

Comment: If the function accepts only a file path, then you need to create a file and pass its path. If it’s private code, try modifying it to accept arrays directly.

Comment: I have a same problem, for example split-image  lib only accept image_path and I am using Rest to read image to memory. Image.open(image_path)

Answer (score 0):

Create a tmpfs filesystem (aka a RAM disk), save the NumPy array as a file there.  This way it won't do any actual disk I/O.

Of course, with modern SSDs I doubt you'll measure any speedup in your overall system.

Comment: Is there a code example you can provide?

Comment: @aryan_461: tmpfs is not code, it's a filesystem you set up then you write files to that filesystem just as if you were writing to an actual disk.